# iPhone pop navigation controller when tab bar selected

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone app with a tab bar and in the first tab there is a `UINavigationController`. How can I force the navigation controller to popToRoot when selecting the tab? The default behaviour does this the second time you select it but I wish to do it on the first one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)’s [`–tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3adidSelectViewController%3a) method to be notified when the user selects the navigation controller. Then, in that method, pop your navigation controller as desired.

Comment: I used this but I don't think I had it setup correctly as it never called. Will look further into it...

Comment: Make sure that somewhere you set the delegate of the tab bar controller. Assuming that you make your application delegate conform to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol, you’d simply use this statement: `tabBarController.delegate = self;` in your application delegate code where you initialize the tab bar.